# Unconfirmed BTC

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

Can anyone tell me how to fix BTC that seems stuck as unconfirmed?

Here is the blockchain info:

https://blockchain.info/tx/37ffff757d1735a8c4fe96a0ee63a7d797e9bc5a858b7a60f81eaf935bee5709?show_adv=true

Comment: Yes, that's weird that it hasn't confirmed yet!  I see that one of the outputs is also spent, in another transaction, also unconfirmed.

Comment: If you want to avoid a transaction to get stuck unconfirmed, you can better include a transaction fee. But nevertheless, this should not happen.

Comment: Looks like it finally got confirmed!

Answer (score -2):

Every ten minutes in the blockchain the transactions are confirmed. So if you want to get 100% fully confirmed you will have to wait an hour. There is not much you can do in the process about that.

Comment: It's been more than 2 hours.  This is odd.

Comment: Alright maybe if you give us a whole lot more details. The OS you are using, what exactly happened; were you running other programs? What was the amount did you set a transaction fee? The more that everyone knows the better we might be able to assist you. Thanks. I just answered you with standard protocol, but I guess you are having a more serious problem.

Comment: You can see the transaction in blockchain.info.  It looks normal.  The only weird thing that I noticed is that is one of its outputs is spent in another unconfirmed transaction.  Maybe this interdependency is slowing things down?